# Magento - finding the block corresponding to a piece of HTML

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento, and one of the things I'm finding awkward when exploring the system is tying a given element in the generated (X)HTML page to the name of the block that created it. I'm aware of System->Configuration->Template Path Hints. However, it is very ugly, sometimes alters the layout of elements on the page, and doesn't show all blocks (I think it only covers template blocks).

An approach I've tried is to modify the `toHtml()` method in Mage_Core_Block_Abstract to add empty elements before and after the content, eg.

```
<blockStart xmlns="http://some/url" name="the_block_name"/>
<!-- the block's contents -->
<blockEnd/>
```

(There may be a way to do this without modifying core files but I don't really mind this approach for now as it's just for my own use. Any ideas welcome, though.)

These elements give me enough information in the document to use jQuery's `.nextUntil()` function on the browser side to add `data-magento-blockname` attributes to the elements between the blockStart and blockEnd elements. I can then use these attributes to display a tooltip containing the full block name "path" to the content under the pointer at any given time.

The problem with this approach is that although Magento produces XHTML with a strict DOCTYPE, it is hard-coded to set Content-Type to "text/html" (see `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` line 1246). This means the XML is interpreted by the browser as HTML "tag soup", resulting in strange things happening - many of my tags disappear altogether, appear in the wrong places or aren't closed immediately so they contain other content. Also, not all of the HTML elements in the document show up in the DOM.

I've tried modifying App.php to change Content-Type to application/xhtml+xml, and this does allow my mechanism to work successfully. However, it has some severe drawbacks:

1. I've had to disable add-ins, particularly Commerce Bug, that don't produce valid XHTML. The loss of Commerce Bug is pretty bad as I really want access to its page and package XML viewing functionality while my add-in is in operation.
2. Much of the javascript included in Magento makes use of document.write(), which doesn't work with XHTML, so I get javascript exceptions and presumably some functionality doesn't work.

Does anybody know of any solutions to these problems with my approach, or know of any easier way to link HTML elements in the output to the Magento blocks that produce them?

Comment: I've struggled with "the right" way to do this for years and haven't come up with anything solid, so I don't have any suggestions there. That said, I hate the thought that Commerce Bug is blocking you from getting your solution working, so I finally fixed up the various XHTML validation errors in the extension.  If you re-download the 1.5.3 version (using your original emailed link), the validation errors should be gone. Email support if you run into any. http://www.pulsestorm.net/blog/2012/10/4/commerce-bug-153-maintenance-release.html

Comment: Alan Storm,  you're a legend :-)  Thank you for this and for  the blog posts,  the book and Commerce Bug,  all of which have helped enormously. With CB working and with a hacky tweak to avoid cases where the block output isn't a collection of elements,  I think my approach might just about tolerable.  Not good enough to package up as an extension but enough to be worth doing on a throwaway magento instance  to help with learning the system. If so,  I might put a blog post together about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** It ended up taking a while, but finally I give you BlockSpy: http://omnicognate.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/blockspy-my-first-magento-extension/

---

**Update** Haven't had much time to work on it, but I've got the server-side part of this working now. By adding my blockStart/blockEnd markers in a `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event handler I've managed to do it without modifying any core files, and by putting them in comments I've got them to pass through HTMLTidy unmolested. The SAX parser bit is working. There's just the javascript client bit to do, which should be straightforward - the idea is to do something in the style of the CSS XRAY bookmarklet (http://westciv.com/xray/).

I'll link to an article about how it works and update and accept this answer once it's done  - if somebody else hasn't come up with a better solution before, of course.

---

I think I'm closing in on a solution to this. It seems the problem really boils down to 3 things:

1. Magento doesn't really produce reliably valid XHTML. For example, there is some inconsistency over using CDATA sections for Javascript. I've run into a few invalid pages, and no doubt there are plenty more.
2. The generation of the page is done in a purely textual fashion. Since the server is manipulating strings, not a DOM, it's not easy to reliably insert markup on the server side. Also, AFAIK there is no guarantee that the blocks' `toHtml()` methods will always produce collections of whole elements. For example, there's nothing stopping you (I think) from having a block that produces text and embedding it inside an attribute value in a parent block, or for opening an XHTML element in a parent block and closing it in a child (though that would be grim).
3. Switching the Content-Type to XHTML, even if the server is persuaded to produce properly valid markup, completely breaks the javascript on the site, and I'm not prepared to go through and update it all to work with XHTML.

I think the following approach may address these problems:

1. Use `PHP::Tidy` on the server side to force the server to produce valid XHTML. I've given this a try by running `tidy_parse_string()` in a `controller_front_send_response_before` handler, and it seems to work.
2. Instead of having the blockStart/blockEnd markers that the Block class inserts processed on the client side, use a SAX XML parser on the server side to process the response before sending it. I can run through the substrings between the markers, passing each substring into the SAX parser as I go (and leaving out the markers). This should allow me to maintain state and build up the output XML string in response to the events the SAX parser generates. I can then insert data-*** attributes safely (if slowly) on the server side.
3. Leave the Content-Type as text/html. This will allow the javascript to work, and the data-*** attributes will be ignored on the client side anyway, as desired.

It's a bit of a pain, but it seems like it should work with all my extensions, avoid breaking the javascript and avoid making any assumptions about what kind of output the blocks produce. I've only tried step one - will update once I've had a crack at the tricky bit :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the XHTML, I was about to try changing the mime type.

Answer (score 2):

When using template path hints, sometimes you need to inspect the element and then find the associated template file listed by looking at in in ChromeDevTools or Firebug (it will be a parent element with a bunch of inline styles).

I use grep quite often to find things as well. Just navigate to the highest folder where you *think* you should be looking (so as not to have to traverse thousands of unrelated folders/files).

So if you know a block name, and want to find which template files use that block, you could go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout and do something like:

```
grep "catalog/category" -r -l .
```

and you should be able to get some file names that are loading that block, then find their declaration nodes and see which template file is being loaded.

```
echo get_class($this)
```

Can also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks,  but these are the kinds of things I wanted to avoid,  if possible.  In theory it should be possible for a system like this to have functionality to link you direct from the html to the block,  but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to add it.

Comment: Yeah I figured - there's theory and then there's what is practical with Magento. After you work with it for awhile, there are many things that just come second nature. Honestly, most of the time it doesn't take me very long to figure out block/template relationships even for non-standard stuff. One thing Magento does very well is give you enough of the information you need to find where things are located.

Comment: I think you're right. It looks like the "right" or at least "normal" way to do this is just to learn to link things up manually.

Comment: I've voted your answer up, but I'm refraining from accepting it yet as I've become mildly obsessed with this now, and I think I may be approaching some kind of solution. It's all highly educational, anyway :-)